React js getting "corrupted" url but with right path and routing
I'm using React-Router-DOM for the routing, and the routes and the URLs are correct, but when I try to enter the product description the URL gets "corrupted" (?), I don't know what to call it. Here is the correct URL "localhost:3000/product/661542f7c301d72e2fb103c4", and here is the url that I get when I navigate to the product descriptions "http://localhost:3000/%7B%60/product/$%7Bproduct._id%7D%60%7D".
App.js:
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import Home from './components/Home';
import ProductDetails from './components/product/ProductDetails';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="container container-fluid">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" Component={Home} exact />
            <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductDetails} exact />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

This is the ProductDetails page, it's just a template for now and has no functionality:
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails, clearErrors } from "../../actions/productActions";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";

const ProductDetails = () => {
  return (
    <div className="row f-flex justify-content-around">
      <div className="col-12 col-lg-5 img-fluid" id="product_image">
        <img
          src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/
                1223a935-2a61-480a-95a1-21904ff8986c_1.17fa3d7870e3d9b1248da7b1144787f5.jpeg?
                odnWidth=undefined&odnHeight=undefined&odnBg=ffffff"
          alt="sdf"
          height="500"
          width="500"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="col-12 col-lg-5 mt-5">
        <h3>onn. 32” className HD (720P) LED Roku Smart TV (100012589)</h3>
        <p id="product_id">Product # sklfjdk35fsdf5090</p>

        <hr />

        <div className="rating-outer">
          <div className="rating-inner"></div>
        </div>
        <span id="no_of_reviews">(5 Reviews)</span>

        <hr />

        <p id="product_price">$108.00</p>
        <div className="stockCounter d-inline">
          <span className="btn btn-danger minus">-</span>

          <input
            type="number"
            className="form-control count d-inline"
            value="1"
            readOnly
          />

          <span className="btn btn-primary plus">+</span>
        </div>
        <button
          type="button"
          id="cart_btn"
          className="btn btn-primary d-inline ml-4"
        >
          Add to Cart
        </button>

        <hr />

        <p>
          Status: <span id="stock_status">In Stock</span>
        </p>

        <hr />

        <h4 className="mt-2">Description:</h4>
        <p>
          Binge on movies and TV episodes, news, sports, music and more! We
          insisted on 720p High Definition for this 32" LED TV, bringing out
          more lifelike color, texture and detail. We also partnered with Roku
          to bring you the best possible content with thousands of channels to
          choose from, conveniently presented through your own custom home
          screen.
        </p>
        <hr />
        <p id="product_seller mb-3">
          Sold by: <strong>Amazon</strong>
        </p>

        <button
          id="review_btn"
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-primary mt-4"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#ratingModal"
        >
          Submit Your Review
        </button>

        <div className="row mt-2 mb-5">
          <div className="rating w-50">
            <div
              className="modal fade"
              id="ratingModal"
              tabIndex="-1"
              role="dialog"
              aria-labelledby="ratingModalLabel"
              aria-hidden="true"
            >
              <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div className="modal-content">
                  <div className="modal-header">
                    <h5 className="modal-title" id="ratingModalLabel">
                      Submit Review
                    </h5>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="close"
                      data-dismiss="modal"
                      aria-label="Close"
                    >
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="modal-body">
                    <ul className="stars">
                      <li className="star">
                        <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                      </li>
                      <li className="star">
                        <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                      </li>
                      <li className="star">
                        <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                      </li>
                      <li className="star">
                        <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                      </li>
                      <li className="star">
                        <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                      </li>
                    </ul>

                    <textarea
                      name="review"
                      id="review"
                      className="form-control mt-3"
                    ></textarea>

                    <button
                      className="btn my-3 float-right review-btn px-4 text-white"
                      data-dismiss="modal"
                      aria-label="Close"
                    >
                      Submit
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;

I'm using Postman for the methods (get, post, delete,...) and this is the method and the response: {{DOMAIN}}/api/v1/product/661542f7c301d72e2fb103c4
{
    "success": true,
    "product": {
        "_id": "661542f7c301d72e2fb103c4",
        "name": "Diamonds - Hip Hop Samples",
        "price": 10,
        "ratings": 4,
        "images": [
            {
                "public_id": "product/productNumber211",
                "url": "//cymatics.fm/cdn/shop/products/diamonds-h1200-min_1080x.png?v=1579721670 1080w",
                "_id": "661542f7c301d72e2fb103c5"
            }
        ],
        "category": "Pack",
        "seller": "Alexandar",
        "numOfReviews": 10,
        "reviews": [],
        "user": "65f9975e64c530b7ccde88f3",
        "createdAt": "2024-04-09T13:30:31.787Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}

and lastly here is the javascript method for getting the product description:
export const getProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCTS_DETAILS_REQUEST });

        const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`);

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCTS_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data.product
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCTS_DETAILS_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message
        });
    }
};


Do you enter this URL manually in your client or are you navigating the client to this URL programmatically? If programmatically, share the code responsible.

"http://localhost:3000/%7B%60/product/$%7Bproduct._id%7D%60%7D" literally decodes to "http://localhost:3000/{`/product/${product._id}`}", so I suspect you incorrectly specified a link target to include the template string literal control characters.


// Decoded URI
console.log(decodeURI("%7B%60/product/$%7Bproduct._id%7D%60%7D")); // "{`/product/${product._id}`}"

// Encoded URI
console.log(encodeURI("{`/product/${product._id}`}")); // "%7B%60/product/$%7Bproduct._id%7D%60%7D"



In other words you have something likely similar to the following:
<Link to="{`/product/${product._id}`}">
  View product
</Link>

When you likely meant to use the template string literal directly:
<Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
  View product
</Link>

I notice also that your app router specifies routes incorrectly, all routes should use the element prop and pass valid JSX.
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="container container-fluid">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

